# Scanner isn't separating text file into tokens

Tags: java, arraylist, text, io

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to have the scanner read a text file and then enter it into an arraylist. Here is my demo program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EmployeeDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

      File emps = new File("Employees.txt");
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(emps); 

     for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     {
         String id = inputFile.next();
         String name = inputFile.next();
         String department = inputFile.next();
         String position = inputFile.next();
         String salary = inputFile.next();
         String yrsofser = inputFile.next(); 

         employees.add(new Employee(id, name, department, position, salary, yrsofser));
      }

      inputFile.close();
      System.out.println(employees);
   }
}
```

And for the text file I'm just using this for now:

```
101000
John Smith
EMS
EMT
21778.00
5
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at EmployeeDemo.main(EmployeeDemo.java:16)
```

I tried having it printing after id and it gives me the id number and then it prints years of service.
I also tried inputFile.hasNext() after id and get false.

Does anyone have an idea on why this could be happening?

Comment: You need to call `nextLine()` to consume the line terminations.

Comment: And maybe just your example: it contains 6 values ; but your code wants to read 6 x 6 values because of that surrounding for loop.

Comment: Actually, the file contains **7** values (tokens), since line 2 is two tokens: `John` and `Smith`. Which means that values were read as `id = "101000"; name = "John"; department = "Smith"; position = "EMS"; salary = "EMT"; yrsofser = "21778.00";`, and the `"5"` was read as `id` of second `Employee`.

Comment: @EJP Thank you! But now that I have added nextLine() I'm getting this error: 'Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
     at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
     at EmployeeDemo.main(EmployeeDemo.java:15)'

Comment: Oops! This was it! I took out employees from the text file to figure out what was going wrong and forgot to fix the for loop. Thank you so much! @GhostCat

Comment: Glad we could figure that, turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, the string tokenisation occurs after each space. So, it will consider that there are 7 tokens (not as 6) in your file because "John" and "Smith" are considered as two separate tokens. So, the last token is considered again as the next value for "id" for the second employees and there wouldn't be any value for the rest of the variables. So, it throws "NoSuchElementException"as there is no more values in the text file to be added.

Answer (score 0):

The first and foremost problem: your input file seems to contain only 6,well 7 lines.

But because of your surrounding for loop, your code expects 6 x 6 lines!

And beyond that: when you know that a certain line contains whole numbers for example, then you could use nextInt() instead of reading flat strings.